# Fullcalendar load static event on ajax call

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to get current event on ajax call when calendar is load. how can it possible? I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    console.log(event.title);
  $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_call1.php',
                //data: {vv:vv},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function( response ) {

                    $("#result").html(response);
                    alert("You Click --"+response);
                }
         })
      }
```

but I can not get any event title on ajax call.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do with the ajax call. If you want to show the title of the clicked event, use the eventClick function of fullcalendar.

Comment: no i dont want to eventClick i want to get current event title on documet.ready() function how can i get it ...

Comment: What do you mean by current event? Fullcalendar has no such thing as current event.

Comment: i want to load ajax call on page load and also get date event on it.